# База данных биологической систематики

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Появилась у меня интересная задачка - биологическая систематика. Каждый живой организм относится к царству, типу, классу и т.п.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Царство Животные*. *Царство* - это таксономический ранг, *Животные* - название таксона.

Но это укороченная систематика. На самом деле названий таксонов намного больше, причём для, например, насекомых их больше, чем для растений. И есть нюансы в именах таксонов в зависимости от принадлежности к флоре или фауне. Например, для фауны (животный мир) таксономический ранг называется - тип, а для фауны (растительный мир) - отдел.

Цель базы данных хранить данные о принадлежности видов к таксономическим рангам. Т.е, например, Еж белогрудый - это вид. И нужно хранить данные о том, в какому царству, типу, классу и т.п. он относится с названиями этих таксонов.

В итоге что имеем:

- 7 основных таксономических рангов. Все организмы можно вписать в эту систему.
- У каждого вида помимо основных 7 могут быть дополнительные промежуточные таксономические ранги (в разном количестве для каждого вида).
- Каждый ранг имеет свой строгий порядок - тип находится под Царством, а Вид над Родом.
- В перспективе нужны возможность построения таксономического древа в виде "дерева папок"

Я попробовал реализовать структуру и вот что вышло:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В первых трёх таблицах (слева направо) я описываю какие есть вообще, например Царства для Флоры и Фауны. А в оставшихся двух таблицах для каждого Вида определяю его принадлежность в Царству, Типу и т.п. Может есть какие-то другие варианты?

**upd**

Получается что-то подобное

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**upd2**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66496/discussion-on-question-by-n-osennij----).